# Can One Obtain or Purchase Development Licenses for QB Desktop Canadian Edition

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

For development purposes, does Intuit make free/lower cost licenses available for QB Desktop Canadian Edition (and we also need US Edition)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For QBD - You need to buy the NFR software. PFB details

Please create an IDN account here - https://member.developer.intuit.com/default.asp?fn=acctRegisterUser

Please go here to purchase the NFR - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0250_qb/0030_nfr_software/nfr_purchase

Purchasing will take about 48 hours to complete.

Once complete, you can download the NFR here - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0250_qb/0030_nfr_software/nfr_download

Doc Link - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0020_connect/create_sample_quickbooks_data

Ref Links - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0250_qb/0030_nfr_software
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0260_pos

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Too bad the site is down :) "We are in the process of upgrading the developer site. At this time NFR Purchases are not available.
We apologize for any inconvenience this may cause."

Comment: It is should be up and working from tomorrow morning. thanks.