# How to work with company file using QuickBooks in Intuit Partner Platform

Tags: c#, intuit-partner-platform

I am a beginner in QuickBook. I have created a .NET application and is able to connect to a QuickBooks Api based app from my application. I have managed to show Blue Dot Menu in my application. 
Now I have a requirement to attach to company file.

**1 -** I would like what this company file is all about and what does it contain ? 
**2 -** How are they created and managed ? 
**3 -** How can I attach or access these files using .NET application ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you can read the common QB terminologies.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0070_glossary

Development related docs are available here -

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started

Using ApiExplorer, you can test all endpoint.

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0007_firstrequest

You can try the sample .net

https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/IPP_Sample_Code/tree/master/QuickbooksAPI/DotNet

.net devkit - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0100_ipp_.net_devkit

**1 -** *I would like what this company file is all about and what does it contain ?*

Company file contains data. Your QBD's data get saved in company file(locally). Comapny file's data gets uploaded to cloud when you sync it. After sync, you get an id(called 'relamId' corresponding to your company file). While calling API endpoints, you use that relamId as a dataSource.

For QBO, all data gets saved in cloud.

**2 -** *How are they created and managed ?*

End-users(company file owners) manage their company files.

**3 -** *How can I attach or access these files using .NET application ?*

In the sample app's web.config, you need to set consumer key, consumer secret and app tokens. Your app's user will go through the OAuth flow to connect their QB account's data(available in cloud) with your app. Your app should use that consumer key, consumer secret, apptoken and releamId to get access token and access secret. Using these tokens, your app will be able to communicate with end-user's data-file.

Hope these info will be useful.

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the reply. But can you please illustrate how to create a company file through QBO and after some reading I get to know that to create a company file I need a software QuickBooks Pro 2013 or something like that. Is this needed in QBD or both QBO and QBD.

Comment: For QBO, there is no company file as such. It is an account.
You can get trial QBO account from here - http://quickbooks.intuit.com/cms

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0007_firstrequest

For QBD, you can refer this old post _ 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796636/can-one-obtain-or-purchase-development-licenses-for-qb-desktop-canadian-edition

Thanks

Comment: very helpful reply.. thanks :) will go through it. One more thing in my Blue Dot Menu I can see a connect button for first time, on clicking which a pop up window shows up, which prompts "Which company would you like to connect to?" under my company i get "Synced with QuickBooks company file: payments test". Is this file default one where can I find it?

Comment: Glad to know that it helped. Please feel free to accept the ans :)

There is no default company/account. Using apiexplorer, you can check if you are getting any company in the company selection screen ( the pop-up window which u hv mentioned). If u get the same , then u can share the screenshot by raising a support ticket.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/9_other_resources/0030_support/0010_submit_support_incidents

thanks

Comment: last question :) so the file I mentioned you was uploaded by client, but is it possible to get it at my end.
would like to add you in skype mine is ajendra.prasad1988  :)

Comment: no, unless the companyfile/qbo account owner gives u access/add u as an user of his/her account. 
I don't have any skype account. If you have any qts, then u can post it here or u can raise a support ticket. I'll be happy to help u if I know the ans :)
thanks

Comment: I have setup the project using the link you refer: https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/IPP_Sample_Code/tree/master/QuickbooksAPI/DotNet. I am getting the data after setting up the values for realmId, accessToken, accessTokenSecret, consumerKey, consumerSecret, dataSourcetype(intialized to QBD). 
code:--> 
var qbdCustomerQuery = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.CustomerQuery();
var qbdCustomers = qbdCustomerQuery.ExecuteQuery<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Customer>(context).ToList();
Does the presence of data indicates that client has earlier uploaded company file?

Comment: yes. Using those tokens, you can call different API endpoints(Account, Customer etc) from ApiExplorer.https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer.

Comment: it means I am able to fetch data from a company file in the .net application(if your yes means same). What does synchronization means? does it mean updating local company file with the one used by online services in IIP... ? Plz correct me if I am wrong. thanks :)

Comment: sync(QBD) - The process of synchronizing your QuickBooks company file data with Intuit online services.
for QBO, there is no concept of sync. As in this case, everything is in cloud. All these are mentioned in the docs which I've mentioned above. Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0070_glossary
thanks

Comment: hi, one more help.. Suppose I have created a company say 'My Company' and it has a datasource say 'mypayments' (its a company file if I'm not wrong), then is it possible to have more than one company file or datasource for the same company..

Comment: Your qts is not very clear to me. what is the difference between 'My Company' and 'mypayments' ? are you using QBD or QBO ?
For QBD, datasource is the synced company file and for QBO, it is the online account. 
Thanks

Comment: How can I show you screenshots ?.. I am using QBD.  thanks :)

Comment: I missed your last comment. Sorry for that. As mentioned earlier, you can raise a support ticket with the screenshot.